# how to add space around = or != in java

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to use regex to search for `=` or `!=` and add space around it.

I was trying:

`string.replaceAll("\\s*\\b=\\b\\s*", " = ");`

However it does not work if `=` leads or follows by a special character, for example:

```
job="waiter"
job"=\"waiter\"
```

What's the correct regex expression for search `=` along. Same for `!=`. However I don't want `"!="` become a `"! ="`. I want :

```
job="waiter" to be job = "waiter"
job!="chef" to be job != "chef"
```

Comment: Try `\s(=|!=)\s`. Your question is not clear to me. Can you explain it in form of inputs and expected outputs.

Comment: What should happen if there are already spaces on one or both sides of the sign? Also, do you want to count all whitespace (including newlines), just the regular ASCII space character, or something else?

Comment: Other combinations of the `=` character you don't want to split: `==`, `+=`, `-=`, ... And what about having it in strings like `"a=b"`

Comment: @Henry, you are right. I don't want split: ==, +=, -=. Just want to search "=" or "!=" as whole word, then add space around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
replaceAll(" *((\\!|=)?)= *", " $1= ");
```

Comment: This transforms `a==b` to `a =  = b`; similar with other operators involving the `=` character. If the input is a general Java program this replacement would break it.

Comment: Can be simplified to `replaceAll(" *[!=]?= *", " $0 ")`.  But you've exceded the scope of the question.  You're matching `=`, `!=`, *and* `==`.

Answer (score 1):

try this pattern:

```
[ ]*[!]?=[ ]*
```

It means "any = with zero or more spaces before/after without one or no ! before"

Answer (score 0):

```
.replaceAll("([^\\s])\\s*?(!?=)\\s*?([^\\s])", "$1 $2 $3")
```